# R: install Rcplex on linux

Tags: r, cplex

I have some trouble installing Rcplex on linux.

I tried:

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="                                      
--with-cplex-dir='/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex'"    Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz
```

then I get this error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘Rcplex’ ...
** package ‘Rcplex’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking ilcplex/cplex.h usability... yes
checking ilcplex/cplex.h presence... yes
checking for ilcplex/cplex.h... yes
checking for library containing CPXversion... no
configure: error: Could not link CPLEX library using -L/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic -l$(CPLEXLIB) -lm -lpthread -ldl
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rcplex’
```

I also tried this:

```
R CMD INSTALL     --configure-args="--with-cplex-include=/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include \
    --with-cplex-cflags=-fPIC \
    --with-cplex-lib=/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic' \
    -lcplex -lm -lpthread'" Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz
```

and get this error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘Rcplex’ ...
** package ‘Rcplex’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking ilcplex/cplex.h usability... yes
checking ilcplex/cplex.h presence... yes
checking for ilcplex/cplex.h... yes
checking for library containing CPXversion... no
configure: error: Could not link CPLEX library using /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic -lcplex -lm -lpthread
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rcplex’
```

Comment: Do the examples run fine when you try `cd /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/examples/x86-64_linux/static_pic && make execute_c`?

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best course of action is to look into what exactly the `configure` script tries to run.  Maybe it expects another version of CPLEX?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem installing the Rcplex 0.3-3 package for R3.6.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 with CPLEX 12.9.

Turns out that the Rcplex package was developed and tested with CPLEX 12.6.3. When I installed this older version of CPLEX on Ubuntu, I was able to install Rcplex 0.3-3 by following the instructions in the INSTALL file.

On my system, this command did the trick:

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="PKG_CFLAGS=-fPIC PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1263/cplex/include PKG_LIBS='-L/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1263/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic -lcplex -lm -lpthread'" Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz
```

This appears to be an issue with the Linux version of Rcplex only. I was able to install Rcplex with the latest version of CPLEX on my Mac.

Comment: I can confirm versions of CPLEX higher than 12.6.3 prevent Rcplex from building in Linux. I use Centos 7.